# Center aligned text is disappearing in Tiny MCE full screen mode on window resizing

Tags: tinymce

Centrally aligned text on editor instance of Tiny disappears. This happens when I re-size the Tiny window in full screen mode. Text appears back when I toggle to normal mode.

Has anybody faced this issue?

I am using Tiny MCE v3.4.8.

Thanks

Comment: The bug is now verified by Tiny dev team See http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5020